# WebDriver qqFileUploader automation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to automate the qqFileUploader embedded in the site. My problem is that the I do not have any access to upload button and even if I had it would open default browse window to which I do not have the access. How can I post the files I want to upload to it? Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using sikuli mixed test with webdriver.

Sikuli can recognize elements on your webpage, and file upload is not a web element, so Selenium cant access it.

Please refer to: http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/

I know this works because I solved it in this was many times, for flash uploader or simple O.S actions.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your file via an standard file input, you should directly write the name of the file in the input :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("inputId")).sendKeys("path/to/your/file");
```